# TestContainer not running on AWS EKS during pull request

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, docker, testcontainers

I have a spring boot application which I am configuring testContainer to run component tests on it. The tests are passing successfully on my machine where I have docker desktop running.But the problem is that when I push the changes on github and the pipeline runs( I am using AWS EKS and jenkinsX3) it fails on maven build step with this error

```
"org.testcontainers.dockerclient.DockerMachineClientProviderStrategy","message":"docker-machine executable was not found on PATH ([/usr/local/openjdk-11/bin, /usr/local/sbin, /usr/local/bin, /usr/sbin, /usr/bin, /sbin, /bin])
```

Based on what I found on different threads I tried to set docker host with these variables and mount the containerd path in maven build step but it's still the same error. Can someone help with this please?

`TESTCONTAINERS_DOCKER_SOCKET_OVERRIDE`

`TESTCONTAINERS_HOST_OVERRIDE`

`DOCKER_HOST`